# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: sizeof(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array

Tags: php, sizeof

The code was working perfectly until I switched to PHP 8

It's all about this line:

```
$brand_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_brands' ) );
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is get_the_terms suppose to return? Looks like it returning a false.

Comment: It probably wasn't working fine before, it probably failed with a warning and you didn't notice. PHP 8 turned lots of warnings into errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix it like this:

```
$brand_count = sizeof ((array)get_the_terms ($post->ID, 'product_brands'));
```